# read data from cache graphql apollo 2.0

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using apollo 2.0. I first make `authUser` `graphql` call to server for given username and password, which generate `jwt` token and return back token in response. I do see that on successful login, `User` is stored in `cache` as `id` key value. 
I do have `Buy` button where I need to make `validateSSOSession` for given `token`. For `validateSSOSession`, I need to read `token` from cache.

I gone through `client.readQuery`, `client.fragementQuery` but both are not applicable for my case bcz  `client.readQuery` expect that same query had been called before to server and I should have same variable. Since I don't have `username/password` therefore I can't call `client.readQuery`. Similarly, `client.fragementQuery` expect `id` as mandatory. Since I don't have `id` therefore can't use it.

For time being, I am simply iterating `data` from `cache` and filtering for `User` as below.

```
const data = client.cache.data.data;
  const users = _.values(data).filter(obj=>(obj.__typename==='User' && obj.token));
  const token = users[0].token;

  // Make graphql call to validate sso
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_SSO_USER,
    variables: { token }
  });

  const authenticated = data.getSingleSignOnUser.user.userId;
```

Is there alternate easy way to query `User` from cache for given condition?

Answer (score 6):

I use `client.readQuery()`. See the docs about that https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.readQuery

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { withApollo } from "react-apollo";

const MY_QUERY = gql`
    query {
      user {email}
    }`;

const MyReactComp = ({client}) =>{
    const someQueryResult = client.readQuery({ query: MY_QUERY });
        return someQueryResult.user ? 'hello user' : 'oops';
    }

export default withApollo(MyReactComp);
```

Comment: hey @proti, what does your data look like in the cache so that `MY_QUERY` is successful? I am having trouble to read data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208333/how-to-read-cache-in-apollo-client-with-angular  thanks 

Comment: regular data object.