# How to read cache in Apollo client with angular

Tags: angular, caching, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am writing to the cache with the `update` function after a mutation using Apollo Client. The cache contains the obj as shown below, and it is working properly.[image]

However, I can't find the right way to read the object in the cache. I am using `readQuery` as mentioned in the docs but I can't find any examples to read objects outside the `ROOT_QUERY`

I have the following code in Angular

```
ngOnInit() {
    const data = this.apollo.getClient().readQuery({
      query: USER,
      variables: {
        id: 'test@email.com',
      },
    });
    console.log(data);
  }
```

And the query is defined like this:

```
const USER = gql`
  query User($id: String!) {
    user(id: $id) @client {
      token
    }
  }
`;
```

Not sure if I have to modify the `typeDefs` or `resolvers` when instantiating Apollo Client?

Thanks